# How to do multiple assignment with return values in ruby (1.9) case statement?

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, variable-assignment

Doing this works fine:

```
q = case period_group
  when 'day' then [7, 'D'] 
  when 'week' then [7, 'WW'] 
  else ['12','MM']
end
limit,pattern = q[0],q[1]
```

But my first try:

```
limit, pattern = case period_group
  when 'day' then 7, 'D' 
  when 'week' then 7, 'WW' 
  else '12','MM'
end
```

ends up in a SyntaxError:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
      when 'day' then 7, 'D'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be returning array for this. Otherwise it confuses the parser.

```
limit, pattern = case period_group
  when 'day' then [7, 'D'] 
  when 'week' then [7, 'WW'] 
  else ['12','MM']
end
```

I don't see why you wanted to get rid of square brackets. It's even more readable that way.

Comment: Thanks. Now I see the good edit. Will upvote the answer when I can.

Comment: Because this is not parallel assignment. About the confusion: parser expects either a single value, or a series of statements, followed by the `end`. Listing values with comma between them is neither.

Comment: Read the question good. My First Try, is a parallel assignment; and I thought that putting the = sign before the 'case' keyword makes it eligible for parallel assigning. But I agree, it is more readable indeed.

Comment: Yes, there is a parallel assignment in your first sample (`limit,pattern = q[0],q[1]`). But when you try to involve a `case` expression, it stops being one. By the way, you could simply write `limit, pattern = q`.

Comment: indeed, but it would be more the ruby way if the intent (on the left hand side of the =) would be reflected in the the syntax of writing the return values, having to surround with square brackets seems to be unruby. Maybe I am wrong. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to put returned values inside []

```
limit, pattern = case period_group
  when 'day' then [7, 'D']     
  when 'week' then [7, 'WW']     
  else ['12','MM']    
end
```